# End of Line Problems

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to download images from my Gmail account using the `gmail` gem. It works fine, except the file downloaded through the gem has `CR + LF` line endings and the actual file has `LF` line endings.

Why is this happening? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Are you on Mac?  I suspect GMail gives you LF line endings seeing basing in your browser's User-Agent.

In any case, proper solution to the problem is to convert text using `universal_newline` converter.  See documentation for ruby built-in converters here: http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9/classes/Encoding/Converter.html

Answer (score 1):

If it's a text file then the line endings are specified by MIME and probably the encoding takes place by the sender of the file ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Content-Transfer-Encoding ).

As to how to fix it, Alex Lebedev had a good option. You could also use Ruby MIME gems to do the conversion.

If you are downloading images, however, the Base64 encoding should be resilient to end-of-line issues.

Hope that helps. The problem is a little vague to me as we're talking line endings and image files (which don't have CRLF endings as a normal part of their encoding). :)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest fix may be to take the result and simply:

```
text.gsub! "\r\n", "\n"
```

Comment: Tried this about a million different ways. Only seems to worsen the problem.

Comment: @c00lryguy I'd suggest that you edit your question with the output of `inspect` on a small sample. What I've posted above will convert CRLF to LF, so perhaps that is not actually your problem.

Comment: My problem is that when I download the attachment from the file, the file is different than when I download it through the `gmail` or `ruby-gmail` gem

Comment: Define "different" if you want help. Also, what platform are you on?

Comment: Different as in the line endings are different.. I clearly stated that.

Comment: @c00lryguy We're volunteering our time and trying to help; I believe that your assumption may be wrong (or else my code above would have helped). Please tell us: 1) What OS you are on; 2) What Ruby version; 3) Create a **small** sample file and read it from disk and from gmail, and for both edit your question with the output of `p my_file_content`. If you are on Windows, be sure to read your file from disk via `my_file_content = File.open(filename,'rb'){ |f| f.read }` to ensure that you are not running afoul of the automatic line ending conversion.